# How to map through map without using key?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, maps

I have a map.

`const example = new Map()`

The example is full of objects with various properties. I needed to map through `example` as an array and create a list of a certain property; the below code works fine.

`const values = Array.from(example).map(([key, value]) => value.property)`

The only problem is that although I read the value `key`, I never use it. Not a huge problem, but my IDE gives me warning about it and it seems inefficient to me. Is there any way to map through `example` without reading the key value? I doubt this has never been asked before, but I could not find any other answers.

Comment: Why don’t you only destructure `value` (or even `property`) out of the array?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I just realized that as you commented haha, thanks anyways.

Comment: use the [`Map.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values) iterator. `[...example.values()].map(v => v.property);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out. To not read the key, just don't declare it.

`const values = Array.from(example).map(([, value]) => value.property)`